# When a string is converted into a list in python, str[n] counts ''," as a list item

Tags: python, list

Am new to python like 1 week.When a string is converted into a list in python, str[n] counts ''," as a list item.I don't want the
commas,to be an item in list.I want the double digit integer to a single item in list

```
data =(str(input("Enter the numbers seperated by commas:")))
l=list(data.split(","))
print("Data is :",l)
print(data[0])
print(data[1])
print(data[2])
print(data[3])
print(data[4])
print("n=",len(data))


Output:
Enter the numbers seperated by commas:9,45,4
Data is : ['9', '45', '4']
9
,
4
5
,
n= 6
```

Comment: You're not using l (the list), but data (the string)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating the original string (`data`) instead of iterating the split result (`l`). Which is also why `45` is iterated as two different items, and you have a length of 6 (rather than 3, despite only 2 commas).

Incidentally, `str.split` returns a list, there's no reason to re-convert that to a list. And `input` returns a string, there is also no reason to re-convert that.

```py
data = input("Enter the numbers seperated by commas:")
items = data.split(",")
print(f"Data is {items} (n={len(items)})")
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.I'm just beginner experimenting myself